# ILightweightLabelDecorator's 'decorate' method is never called

Tags: java, swt, jface, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I'm trying to add an overlay picture to the specific item of a `TreeViewer`. I have read 10+ posts on stackoverflow and other Google results about `ILightweightLabelDecorator`.

But I meet the same problem with [this guy](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/139790/) : the `ILightweightLabelDecorator`'s `decorate` method is never called.

Here are what I've done:

```
...
viewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);
viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
viewer.setLabelProvider(new MyViewLabelProvider());
...

//the MyViewLabelProvider class
public class MyViewLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements ILightweightLabelDecorator{

    public void decorate(Object element, IDecoration decoration) {
        if(element instanceof MyObject){
            decoration.addOverlay(ImageUtil.getImageDescriptor("icons/decorate.gif"), IDecoration.TOP_RIGHT);
        }
    }

    ...
```

After all of those things done, it still remains not working, so I even tried the declarative way in the *plugin.xml* but the `decorate` method is still never called.

```
<decorator
    lightweight="true"
    location="TOP_RIGHT"
    label="ViewLabelProvider Decorator"
    class="com.myplugin.MyViewLabelProvider"
    id="com.myplugin.viewlabelprovider.decorator"
    state="true">
 <enablement>
    <objectClass name="com.myplugin.model.MyObject"/>        
 </enablement>
</decorator>
```

Did I miss something? Anybody give some hints?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingLabelProvider` for your label provider, like this:

```
viewer.setLabelProvider(new DecoratingLabelProvider(your label provider,
             PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager().getLabelDecorator()));
```

Normally your label provider just extends `LabelProvider` and you use a separate class to implement `ILightweightLabelDecorator`.

Update:

If you just want to add overlays on images in your label provider you can use `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecorationOverlayIcon`. Something like:

```
DecorationOverlayIcon decoratedImage = new DecorationOverlayIcon(img, overlay, IDecoration.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
```

Note: you need to dispose any images you create this way.

Comment: It's just a spelling mistake , and I used your code not still not be called

Comment: My code works with the <decorator> declaration in the plugin.xml. Check that your decorator is showing up in Preferences > General > Appearance > Label Decorations and that it is enabled.

Comment: Not good. In my situation, I don't think I need the declarative way in the plugin.xml to do this. But the programmatic way do fail. Tks for your patience.

Comment: Added info about DecorationOverlayIcon

Answer (score 1):

Check if this post of mine helps. It has step by step procedure of using a decorator

http://subhankarc.blogspot.in/2012/05/decorator-in-eclipse-jface-treeviewer.html